# how to resolve error PRJ0002 : Error result -1073741515 returned from 'cl.exe'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have tried to see my functions using `dump.exe` and `link.exe` through visual studio command line.

After that IDE not working fine. I got the following error

> error PRJ0002 : Error result -1073741515 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'

How to resolve this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`-1073741515 == 0xFFFF FFFF C000 0135 == STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`

Which basically means, that `cl.exe` is unable to start, because it can not load some dynamic link library. It seems, that you managed to corrupt your Visual Studio installation and reinstall/repair is in order.